# What causes a Sitecore module not to work in Sitecore Instance Manager (SIM)?

Tags: sxa, sim

I remember having the problem awhile ago but I cannot find the solution again using Google etc. So I thought I'd post on here.

I'm trying to add a module so that it can be selected in the instance creation wizard. I can select from many other modules including WFFM.

But I cannot see Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA) when I place it in the repository directory or select it to be added during the process which prompts "Selected file is not a Sitecore module package".

I'm downloading SXA v1.2 from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/12/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_12_Initial_Release.aspx.

The package contents look correct but I cannot remember what typically breaks these packages for SIM. I'm sure it was something simple :)

Comment: There are two steps when you can add additional packages/modules: `Modules list` and `Custom Packages`. Have you tried the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you download the package the default filenames for SXA are **Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.2 rev. 161216 for 8.1.zip** and **Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.2 rev. 161216 for 8.2.zip**.

Rename the file removing everything after the revision number and it will then show up in the Modules list, i.e. rename the file to **Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.2 rev. 161216.zip**

[image: SIM Module List]

Comment: Cheers Kam that's got it! Is this true for any module the suffixes the module name?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. My assumption is that it expects the filename in a specific format in order to then group the modules and populate the version/revision droplist. SIM is open source and [the code on Github](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Instance-Manager) if you wish to investigate further,

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll checkout the code. Cheers buddy!